# Enumerate list to make a new list of indices?

Tags: python, enumerate

I'm trying to make a new list of indices by enumerated a previous list. Basically, what I want is:

To enumerate a list of elements to obtain indices for each element. I coded this:

```
board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]
for index,y in enumerate(board):
    print(index,end=" ")
```

which gives:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

I now want to make those numbers into a new list, but have no clue how to do that.

Thanks! Sorry for the question, I'm still a beginner and am just trying to get the hang of things.

Comment: You shouldn't apologize for the question. While you may have found the solution by searching a bit more, you posted a good quality question that was well-formatted. Have fun learning Python!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just make a range of the right length:

```
board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]
indices = list(range(len(board)))
print(indices)
> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Ahh, that's a lot simpler. But how could I print it so that it appears as 0 1 2 3 4, as opposed to [0,1,2,3,4,]?

Comment: `print(' '.join(indices))`   https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Thanks! I tried that and unfortunately got an error, since the elements in the new list are integers. I just coded print(" ".join(str(i) for i in new)) and got it though, so it finally works now!

Comment: You could use `map` for that, too: `print(' '.join(map(str,indices)))`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension:

```
indices = [index for index, y in enumerate(board)]
```

If `board` is always a object, which implements the `__len__`-method, you can also use `range`:

```
indices = list(range(len(board)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want all the numbers you can use this:

```
indices = list(range(len(board)))
```

If you pass one number to range it will return an iterator with the numbers 0 up to the passed number (excluding). After this we turn it into a list with the list function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to do that:

```
result = [index for index,y in enumerate(board)]
```

Alternatively you can use the `range` function:

```
result = range(len(board))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use numpy arange, which creates an array that looks like the one you are looking for: 
[Numpy Arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

```
import numpy as np

enumerated = np.arange(len(board))
```

Comment: I would think `numpy` or any external library to be overkill for this problem. The OP is a beginner, so maybe this is not the best approach at this time.

Comment: True that. Start with the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is:

```
board = ["O","O","O","O","O"]
newlist = []
for index,y in enumerate(board):
    newlist.append(index)
```

A more advanced way using list comprehensions would be:

```
newlist = [index for index, value in enumerate(board)]
```